# if integral $f(x)\cdot g(x)=0$ mean that $f(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

The question:

> If $f(x)$ is a continuous function, such that for every continuous function $g(x)$ defined over $[a,b]$ $$\int_a^b f(x)\cdot g(x)\,dx =0$$ does it mean that $f\equiv 0$?

The solution in the website is: we equalize $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ thus:$$\int_a^b f(x)^2\,dx =0$$ (and from similar question we know that $f=0$)

my problem with that solution is that: this is lonely case of $g(x)$ and we cannot say it equal to $f(x)$ and then say that $f=0$, because the question is for every $g(x)$. Does I didn't understand it right or the solution is incorrect? Does you have diffrent proof?

Comment: is the $*$ supposed to be a normal multiplication?

Comment: yes sorry about it...

Comment: @Yagel You can also prove it by absurd using a very similar idea. Suppose $f\not\equiv0.$ Then if you take $g=f$... Maybe it is more clear.

Answer (score 4):

The answer the website gave you is correct. if it says "for every $g$", then it should also hold for the special case of $f$.

Additional Example for the same logical problem:
If you say, that you shower every day, then it follows, that you showered yesterday. "yesterday" is just a special case of "every day", but one implies the other.

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand. if  $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)=0$$ but g(x) is not equal to f(x), how f=0? If i want to proof something I can't just show example

Comment: it is important, that $\int fg \, dx=0$ holds for EVERY continuous $g$. that means, you can also take $g=f$.

Comment: can't it be that I take g(x)=sin(x), and $$\int_a^b f(x)sin(x)=0$$ but f is not equal to 0?

Comment: yes, $\int_a^b f(x) \sin (x) \, dx = 0$ is also true, and also for $g(x)=cos(x)$, $g(x)=x$, $g(x)=1233232$ and every other continous function you can imagine. one of these continous functions is $f$.

Answer (score 1):

It's too long for a comment, but I think you can get it using this argument. Suppose that $f\not\equiv0
 $ and take $g=f
 $. Than we have $$\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx=0.
 $$ Now $f
 $ is continuous, then exists $\left[c,d\right]\subseteq\left[a,b\right]
 $ such that $f\left(x\right)\neq0,\:\forall x\in\left[c,d\right]
 $ hence $f^{2}\left(x\right)>0,\:\forall x\in\left[c,d\right]
 $. We also note that, by Weiestrass theorem, $f^{2}
 $ has a minimum on $\left[c,d\right]
 $, say $f^{2}\left(m\right)>0
 $. Then $$0=\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\int_{c}^{d}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx\geq f^{2}\left(m\right)\left(d-c\right)>0
 $$ and this is absurd.